# the problem about crossing the huffman tree on haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a problem about type mapping in creating a Huffman tree code map. I do almost everything according to the template to figure out how it works, but I have problems creating a code card.

```
class Eq a => Bits a where
    zer :: a
    one :: a
 
instance Bits Int where
    zer = 0
    one = 1

instance Bits Bool where
    zer = False
    one = True

type Codemap a = M.Map Char [a]

main = do
    st <- getLine
    h <- openFile st ReadMode 
    (s:sp) <- getlines h
    let xs = asslist (listik (s:sp))
    let df =  buildTree xs
    let d = buildCodemap df
    print df


buildCodemap :: Bits a => Tree -> Codemap a
buildCodemap = M.fromList . buildCodelist
    where  buildCodelist (Leaf c w)    = [(c, [])]
           buildCodelist (Fork l r w)  = map (addBit zer) (buildCodelist l) ++ map (addBit one) (buildCodelist r)
                        where addBit b = second (b :)
```

As a result, when I check this function, it write me this:

```
Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘buildCodemap’
prevents the constraint ‘(Bits a0)’ from being solved.

  Relevant bindings include
```

By the way, type `Codemap a` became `Codemap Any`.

Comment: You need to specify `a` somehow, e.g. `buildCodemap someTree :: Codemap Int`, when you call the function.

Comment: Do you really need that typeclass? Can't you just use a `data Bit = Zero | One` type and then convert as needed?

Comment: Another option you have is to give `buildCodeGeneric` a higher rank type - `Tree -> (forall a. Bits a => Codemap a)`. (Requires the `RankNTypes` or `Rank2Types` extension to be enabled). Then the return value can be passed around without giving it a concrete type.